# Anyone using Change Data Capture for Replication?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm soon going to be involved in a project to replace our current method of replication from transactional replication to some other method (for various reasons). I'm considering using CDC as an alternate method. I'm envisioning CDC capturing all the changes and then another process would read the changes and apply them to a target database.

I don't know much about CDC and whether it's suitable for this task. Can anyone let me know of your experience doing this, or something closely related? Pros and cons, pitfalls etc.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Can you explain why are you trying to replace Replication, what are the pitfals/problems etc? Ultimately CDC *is* replication in a different skin (is based on on exactly the same technologies and tools) so you may be trading the bird in hand for ... the same bird but not in hand.

Comment: What are your issues w/ transactional replication?

Answer (score 0):

We've been looking into the same thing. Our issue w/ replication has been the tight schema coupling. CDC allows for mostly the same functionality, without the schema coupling.

I think it's doable, but you may be reinventing the wheel. The typical use case for CDC is OLTP -> Data Warehouse, where schemas are completely different, and the data only moves in one direction.